# How to get the distance between two addresses

Tags: java, android

I need to calculate the distance between two addresses. The addresses are given as a string (street, city, country). All I have found is the distance between two locations. I tried to convert the addresses to locations but it didn't work.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Straight line distances? or actual travel time distances? The latter is significantly harder. You have the right approach though, to convert addresses to GPS co-ordinates and then calculate the distance between them.

Comment: straight line distances. I tried to convert the addresses to locations and then calculate the distances but it didn't work. I am always getting a grpc fail error. I googled it and there was no solutions. Lot of people are having this problem. So if there is another solution it will be great. Thanks for you reply

Answer (score 1):

#### Linear Distance

You need to convert the addresses to `Latitute` and `Longitude`.

Google Geocoding API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Afterwards you can get the distance with

```
Location locationA = new Location("");
locationA.setLatitude("my_A_lat");
locationA.setLongitude("my_A_lon");

Location locationB = new Location("");
locationB.setLatitude("my_B_lat");
locationB.setLongitude("my_B_lon");

distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

#### Travel distance

If you would like to get the distance and time used in traffic you can use the Google Distance Matrix API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start

Comment: Hi Philipp thank you for your reply! I have tried to convert the addresses to locations and then calculate the distances between them but I am always getting a grpc error. For this problem I think there is no solution. Is there any other solution?

Comment: How did you convert the addresses? What was the Output from `LogCat`. Please edit your question and provide code snippets of your progress and outcome.